# Ctrl + Z en consola en Windows 10

Tags: c#

Muy buenas, estoy estudiando programación con un libro llamado Microsoft C# Curso de programación de Fco.Javier Ceballos, hay una parte que dice que apretado Ctrl + Z en la consola la consola detecta que es el fin  de la introducción de la información pero cuando yo en mi app de consola y presiono Ctrl + Z no pasa nada sigue recibiendo datos ¿Por qué pasa esto??

Answer (score 0):

Sería interesante saber qué sistema operativo estás empleando (Windows, Linux, Mac)

**Linux/Mac**:
Tu "error" se debe al comportamiento de <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> y su diferencia respecto a <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. En un terminal Linux/Mac:

- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>: envía una señal de interrupción `SIGINT` que casua que se aborte la ejecución.
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>: envía una señal `SIGSTOP` que pone la aplicación en pausa y la envía a *backgroung*. Ésta no se ha detenido, sigue disponible y para seguir trabajando con ella basta con emplear el comando `fg`.

**Windows**:
(No tengo conocimientos exactos, asumo que debe ser igual. Si alguien es conocedor, siéntase libre de editar esta sección)